# Clicking on the search button in JFrame is not opening the JDialog

Tags: java, swing

I have a jframe with page navigation buttons,print,search buttons.When i clicked on the print button it is perfectly opening the window and i am able to print the page also.But when i clicked on search button i am not able to get the window.My requirement is clicking on the Search button should open a window(same as print window) with text field and when i enter the search data then it should display the matches and unmatches.

I have tried the below code but i am not succeed.

```
import com.google.common.base.CharMatcher;
import com.sun.pdfview.PDFFile;
import com.sun.pdfview.PDFPage;
import com.sun.pdfview.PDFRenderer;
import com.sun.pdfview.PagePanel;

import javax.print.attribute.HashPrintRequestAttributeSet;
import javax.print.attribute.standard.PageRanges;
import javax.swing.*;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.geom.AffineTransform;
import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D;
import java.awt.print.PageFormat;
import java.awt.print.Printable;
import java.awt.print.PrinterException;
import java.awt.print.PrinterJob;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.RandomAccessFile;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.channels.FileChannel;

import static com.google.common.base.Strings.isNullOrEmpty;

public class PdfViewer extends JPanel {
    private static enum Navigation {
        GO_FIRST_PAGE, FORWARD, BACKWARD, GO_LAST_PAGE, GO_N_PAGE
    }

    private static final CharMatcher POSITIVE_DIGITAL = CharMatcher.anyOf("0123456789");
    private static final String GO_PAGE_TEMPLATE = "%s of %s";
    private static final int FIRST_PAGE = 1;
    private int currentPage = FIRST_PAGE;
    private JButton btnFirstPage;
    private JButton btnPreviousPage;
    private JTextField txtGoPage;
    private JButton btnNextPage;
    private JButton btnLastPage;
    private JButton print;
    private JButton search;
    private PagePanel pagePanel;
    private PDFFile pdfFile;

    public PdfViewer() {
        initial();
    }

    private void initial() {
        setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));
        JPanel topPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));
        add(topPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        btnFirstPage = createButton("|<<");
        topPanel.add(btnFirstPage);
        btnPreviousPage = createButton("<<");
        topPanel.add(btnPreviousPage);
        txtGoPage = new JTextField(10);
        txtGoPage.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.CENTER);
        topPanel.add(txtGoPage);
        btnNextPage = createButton(">>");
        topPanel.add(btnNextPage);
        btnLastPage = createButton(">>|");
        topPanel.add(btnLastPage);
        print = new JButton("print");
        topPanel.add(print);
        search = new JButton("search");
        topPanel.add(search);
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
        add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        JPanel viewPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout(0, 0));
        scrollPane.setViewportView(viewPanel);

        pagePanel = new PagePanel();
        Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
        pagePanel.setPreferredSize(screenSize);
        viewPanel.add(pagePanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        disableAllNavigationButton();

        btnFirstPage.addActionListener(new PageNavigationListener(Navigation.GO_FIRST_PAGE));
        btnPreviousPage.addActionListener(new PageNavigationListener(Navigation.BACKWARD));
        btnNextPage.addActionListener(new PageNavigationListener(Navigation.FORWARD));
        btnLastPage.addActionListener(new PageNavigationListener(Navigation.GO_LAST_PAGE));
        txtGoPage.addActionListener(new PageNavigationListener(Navigation.GO_N_PAGE));
        print.addActionListener(new PrintUIWindow());
        search.addActionListener(new Action1());
    }

    static class Action1 implements ActionListener {        
          public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e) {  
              JFrame parent = new JFrame();
              JDialog jDialog = new JDialog();
              Label label = new Label("Enter Word: ");
              final JTextField jTextField = new JTextField(100);
              JPanel panel = new JPanel();
              parent.add(panel);
              panel.add(label);
              panel.add(jTextField);
              parent.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
          }
        }   

    private JButton createButton(String text) {
        JButton button = new JButton(text);
        button.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(55, 20));

        return button;
    }

    private void disableAllNavigationButton() {
        btnFirstPage.setEnabled(false);
        btnPreviousPage.setEnabled(false);
        btnNextPage.setEnabled(false);
        btnLastPage.setEnabled(false);
    }

    private boolean isMoreThanOnePage(PDFFile pdfFile) {
        return pdfFile.getNumPages() > 1;
    }

    private class PageNavigationListener implements ActionListener {
        private final Navigation navigation;

        private PageNavigationListener(Navigation navigation) {
            this.navigation = navigation;
        }

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if (pdfFile == null) {
                return;
            }

            int numPages = pdfFile.getNumPages();
            if (numPages <= 1) {
                disableAllNavigationButton();
            } else {
                if (navigation == Navigation.FORWARD && hasNextPage(numPages)) {
                    goPage(currentPage, numPages);
                }

                if (navigation == Navigation.GO_LAST_PAGE) {
                    goPage(numPages, numPages);
                }

                if (navigation == Navigation.BACKWARD && hasPreviousPage()) {
                    goPage(currentPage, numPages);
                }

                if (navigation == Navigation.GO_FIRST_PAGE) {
                    goPage(FIRST_PAGE, numPages);
                }

                if (navigation == Navigation.GO_N_PAGE) {
                    String text = txtGoPage.getText();
                    boolean isValid = false;
                    if (!isNullOrEmpty(text)) {
                        boolean isNumber = POSITIVE_DIGITAL.matchesAllOf(text);
                        if (isNumber) {
                            int pageNumber = Integer.valueOf(text);
                            if (pageNumber >= 1 && pageNumber <= numPages) {
                                goPage(Integer.valueOf(text), numPages);
                                isValid = true;
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    if (!isValid) {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(PdfViewer.this,
                                format("Invalid page number '%s' in this document", text));
                        txtGoPage.setText(format(GO_PAGE_TEMPLATE, currentPage, numPages));
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        private void goPage(int pageNumber, int numPages) {
            currentPage = pageNumber;
            PDFPage page = pdfFile.getPage(currentPage);
            pagePanel.showPage(page);
            boolean notFirstPage = isNotFirstPage();
            btnFirstPage.setEnabled(notFirstPage);
            btnPreviousPage.setEnabled(notFirstPage);
            txtGoPage.setText(format(GO_PAGE_TEMPLATE, currentPage, numPages));
            boolean notLastPage = isNotLastPage(numPages);
            btnNextPage.setEnabled(notLastPage);
            btnLastPage.setEnabled(notLastPage);
        }

        private boolean hasNextPage(int numPages) {
            return (++currentPage) <= numPages;
        }

        private boolean hasPreviousPage() {
            return (--currentPage) >= FIRST_PAGE;
        }

        private boolean isNotLastPage(int numPages) {
            return currentPage != numPages;
        }

        private boolean isNotFirstPage() {
            return currentPage != FIRST_PAGE;
        }
    }

    private class PrintUIWindow implements Printable, ActionListener {

        /*
         * (non-Javadoc)
         * 
         * @see java.awt.print.Printable#print(java.awt.Graphics,
         * java.awt.print.PageFormat, int)
         */
        @Override
        public int print(Graphics graphics, PageFormat pageFormat, int pageIndex) throws PrinterException {
            int pagenum = pageIndex+1;
              if (pagenum < 1 || pagenum > pdfFile.getNumPages ())
                  return NO_SUCH_PAGE;

              Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) graphics;
              AffineTransform at = g2d.getTransform ();

              PDFPage pdfPage = pdfFile.getPage (pagenum);

              Dimension dim;
              dim = pdfPage.getUnstretchedSize ((int) pageFormat.getImageableWidth (),
                                                (int) pageFormat.getImageableHeight (),
                                                pdfPage.getBBox ());

              Rectangle bounds = new Rectangle ((int) pageFormat.getImageableX (),
                                                (int) pageFormat.getImageableY (),
                                                dim.width,
                                                dim.height);

              PDFRenderer rend = new PDFRenderer (pdfPage, (Graphics2D) graphics, bounds,
                                                  null, null);
              try
              {
                  pdfPage.waitForFinish ();
                  rend.run ();
              }
              catch (InterruptedException ie)
              {
                  //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (this, ie.getMessage ());
              }

              g2d.setTransform (at);
              g2d.draw (new Rectangle2D.Double (pageFormat.getImageableX (),
                      pageFormat.getImageableY (),
                      pageFormat.getImageableWidth (),
                      pageFormat.getImageableHeight ()));

              return PAGE_EXISTS;
        }

        /*
         * (non-Javadoc)
         * 
         * @see
         * java.awt.event.ActionListener#actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent
         * )
         */
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            System.out.println("Inside action performed");
            PrinterJob printJob = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
            printJob.setPrintable(this);
             try
              {
                  HashPrintRequestAttributeSet attset;
                  attset = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet ();
                  //attset.add (new PageRanges (1, pdfFile.getNumPages ()));
                  if (printJob.printDialog (attset))
                      printJob.print (attset);
              }
              catch (PrinterException pe)
              {
                  //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (this, pe.getMessage ());
              }

        }

    }

    public PagePanel getPagePanel() {
        return pagePanel;
    }

    public void setPDFFile(PDFFile pdfFile) {
        this.pdfFile = pdfFile;
        currentPage = FIRST_PAGE;
        disableAllNavigationButton();
        txtGoPage.setText(format(GO_PAGE_TEMPLATE, FIRST_PAGE, pdfFile.getNumPages()));
        boolean moreThanOnePage = isMoreThanOnePage(pdfFile);
        btnNextPage.setEnabled(moreThanOnePage);
        btnLastPage.setEnabled(moreThanOnePage);
    }

    public static String format(String template, Object... args) {
        template = String.valueOf(template); // null -> "null"
        // start substituting the arguments into the '%s' placeholders
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(template.length() + 16 * args.length);
        int templateStart = 0;
        int i = 0;
        while (i < args.length) {
            int placeholderStart = template.indexOf("%s", templateStart);
            if (placeholderStart == -1) {
                break;
            }
            builder.append(template.substring(templateStart, placeholderStart));
            builder.append(args[i++]);
            templateStart = placeholderStart + 2;
        }
        builder.append(template.substring(templateStart));

        // if we run out of placeholders, append the extra args in square braces
        if (i < args.length) {
            builder.append(" [");
            builder.append(args[i++]);
            while (i < args.length) {
                builder.append(", ");
                builder.append(args[i++]);
            }
            builder.append(']');
        }

        return builder.toString();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            long heapSize = Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory();
            System.out.println("Heap Size = " + heapSize);

            JFrame frame = new JFrame("PDF Test");
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

            // load a pdf from a byte buffer
            File file = new File("/home/swarupa/Downloads/2626OS-Chapter-5-Advanced-Theme.pdf");
            RandomAccessFile raf = new RandomAccessFile(file, "r");
            FileChannel channel = raf.getChannel();
            ByteBuffer buf = channel.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_ONLY, 0, channel.size());
            final PDFFile pdffile = new PDFFile(buf);
            PdfViewer pdfViewer = new PdfViewer();
            pdfViewer.setPDFFile(pdffile);
            frame.add(pdfViewer);
            frame.pack();
            frame.setVisible(true);

            PDFPage page = pdffile.getPage(0);
            pdfViewer.getPagePanel().showPage(page);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Where i am doing wrong.Can any one point me.

Comment: *Where i am doing wrong* ... dumping your whole code here is wrong. If one button does not work, reduce your code until it only contains that button and the relevant logic behind that button before posting here. See [SSCCE](http://sscce.org)

Comment: `1)` remove `pdf` (3rd. sides or custom APIs) `2)` why is there `static class Action1 implements ActionListener {` that can to recreating whole `GUI` `3)` for better help sooner post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), short, runnable, compilable, just about `JFrame` and `JDialog`, nothing else

Answer (score 2):

I think, that this should solve your problem ;) You've forgotten to set the window to be visible :)

```
static class Action1 implements ActionListener {        
      public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e) {  
          JFrame parent = new JFrame();
          JDialog jDialog = new JDialog();
          Label label = new Label("Enter Word: ");
          final JTextField jTextField = new JTextField(100);
          JPanel panel = new JPanel();
          parent.add(panel);
          panel.add(label);
          panel.add(jTextField);
          parent.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
          parent.setVisible(true);
      }
    }
```

Btw-why do you create that JDialog?

Comment: Hi Dworza thanks for giving the reply.With the above code i am getting a frame with text field.It is fine.But the frame has close(x),minimize(-),Restore buttons.But i need that my frame has only close option as print.Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

You create `JDialog` and `JFrame`, why? You never call setVisible(true), why?

What you expect from the Action1?

Comment: Hi StanislavL Thanks For Giving the reply.From Action1 i need a window which contains the label with textfield.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for posting this answer to your comment as a new post, but it was too long to post it as a comment. You just can't remove close and minimize buttons from JFrame. If you want some window without those buttons, you have to create and customize your own JDialog. Nevertheless there will still be a close button (X). You can make your JDialog undecorated and make it to behave more like JFrame when you implement something like this:

```
class CustomizedDialog extends JDialog {
public CustomizedDialog(JFrame frame, String str) {
    super(frame, str);
    super.setUndecorated(true);
    addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
        public void windowClosing(WindowEvent evt) {
            System.exit(0);
        }
    });
}
```

}

And then you can call it in your code with this:

```
CustomizedDialog myCustomizedDialog = new CustomizedDialog(new JFrame(), "My title");
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
panel.setSize(256, 256);
myCustomizedDialog.add(panel);
myCustomizedDialog.setSize(256, 256);
myCustomizedDialog.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
myCustomizedDialog.setVisible(true);
```

I hope, this helps :)